# JavaScript get the last number in a string and replace it with its next

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
let str = "c-fl_1"
```

and I need to replace the last number '1' with its next '2', so the result string will look like:

```
"c-fl_2"
```

Also I need to do that with all the strings which follow this format... For example, the string "c-fl_9102" should change to "c-fl_9103".

Currently I am doing this, and working fine

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\d+$'), (parseInt(str.match(new RegExp('\\d+$'))) + 1).toString());
```

but I need a more elegant, legible and efficient solution.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: „but I need a more elegant, legible and efficient solution“ why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `replacer` method

```js
let str = "c-fl_1"

let res = str.replace(new RegExp('\\d+$', 'g'), (match) => +match + 1);

console.log(res)
```